# Iteration over an array of objects

Tags: arrays, for-loop, object, foreach, iterator

I have an array of objects from which I intend to copy few of its fields to a different object values on a specific condition

`fromPage: "home";`

````
        sample = [
        {iD:100A,fName:"jack",age:28},
        {iD:200A,fName:"kate",age:29},
        {iD:300A,fName:"rose",age:30}
        ]```

  `    copyObj = [{id:string, name:string}]  `
````

Expecting result:

```
          copyObj = [
             {id:100A,name:"jack"},
             {id:100B,name:"kate"}
                       ]
```

I want to copy these specific fields to my copyObj from the sample. I tried in below way but ended up getting undefined.

```
            for(var i=0;i<=sample.length;i++){
            if(this.fromPage == "home")
            {
             this.copyObj[i].id = this.sample[i].iD;
             this.copyObj[i].name = this.sample[i].fName;
             }
         }
```

The above is throwing error like: cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

Any other way to implement this , please help. I also tried using forEach to iterate and then push the values to the new array but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
this.copyObj=[];
 for(var i=0;i<=this.sample.length-1;i++){
   if(this.fromPage === "home"){
      this.copyObj.push({'id':this.sample[i].iD,'name':this.sample[i].fName});
    }
 }
```

Comment: You have missed -1 in for loop I guess. for(var i=0;i<= this.sample.length-1; i++)

Comment: fromPage: string = "home";
  sample = [
        {'iD':100,'fName':"jack1",'age':28},
        {'iD':200,'fName':"jack2",'age':28},
        {'iD':300,'fName':"jack3",'age':28}
        ];

 public format(){
   this.copyObj=[];
   for(let i=0;i<=this.sample.length-1;i++){
      if(this.fromPage === 'home'){ 
        let tempObj={'id':this.sample[i].iD,
                        'name':this.sample[i].fName};
        this.copyObj.push(tempObj);
         } 
         console.log(this.copyObj);
      }
 }

 ngOnInit(){
        this.format();
 }

Comment: It worked like a charm :-) , Thanks for your time and contribution Geethanjali R